# Remove a row in Datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components

How do i remove a row in a datatable via javascript. I created a table where you can add and delete a row. But I tried to remove it using array.splice but it wont delete.

```
<div class="table-accounts">
            <lightning-datatable 
                data={accounts}
                columns={columns}
                key-field="Id"
                show-row-number-column=true
                onrowselection={getSelectedAccount}
                onrowaction={handleRowAction}
                class="ls-datatable slds-m-around--x-small"
                min-column-width="185px">
            </lightning-datatable>  
        </div>
```

the javascript I set arrnum as the index of array via foreach. It does remove but it removes the 1st row.

```
    handleRemove(event){
    const action = event.detail.action;
    const row = event.detail.row;
    if(action.name === "edit_existing_item" ){

        this.editData = JSON.stringify(row);
        this.template.querySelector("c-account-case-study-edit").handleValueChange(row);
    }else if(action.name === "delete_item"){

        this.accounts.splice(row.Id, 1);
        this.accounts = [...this.accounts];

    }

}

handleadd(event){

    let data = event.detail;
    this.number = this.number + 1;
    let str = data.name.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/ig, "_");
    let ran = "newcase" + str + this.number;
    let newarray ={
        Id: ran,
        recordId: ran,
        Name: data.name,
        Type: data.type,
        Industry:data.industry

    };

    

    this.accounts.unshift(newarray);
    console.log(newarray);
    this.accounts = [...this.accounts];
    
 
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `row.Id` correspond to the item index in the table, try debugging it's value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let ran = "newcase" + str + this.number;
```

This means that Id is something like "newcaseabcd1", which is not the index of the row to remove, but instead a string value. Use either filter or findIndex:

```
this.accounts = this.accounts.filter(account => row.Id !== account.Id);
```

Or:

```
this.accounts.splice(this.accounts.findIndex(account => row.Id === account.Id), 1);
this.accounts = [...this.accounts];
```